# why xsd:key xsd:keyref dont work on xml file?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

i must use xsd:key instead of xsd:ID so
i used this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.checkbook.com/checkbook" xmlns="http://www.checkbook.com/checkbook" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="Serhat">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Serhat2" type="type">
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="PackageNameKey">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Serhat2"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:key>
  </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="type">
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

but key dont work i can take similar id attribute;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Serhat xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.checkbook.com/checkbook" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.checkbook.com/checkbook denemeXSD.xsd">
  <Serhat2 id="ser"/>
  <Serhat2 id="ser"/>
</Serhat>
```

why dont understand.Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me (I just added prefix for your namespace) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.checkbook.com/checkbook" xmlns:ns="http://www.checkbook.com/checkbook" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Serhat">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Serhat2" type="ns:type">
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="PackageNameKey">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//ns:Serhat2"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:key>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="type">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Yeah it worked thanx.But don't understand when i give default namespace it wont work

Comment: XPath does not have default namespaces. You must always be explicit in an XPath.

Comment: thanx.And one more question: can i do this code? <xsd:keyref name="ClassSuperClassNameKeyRef" refer="ns:ClassNameKey | ns:PackageClassNameKey">

Comment: @gezgin : no you can't, the `refer` attribute accepts only QName